# Multiple Canvas Elements in same lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, canvas

Im having issues with having multiple canvas LWC nested in one same parent LWC.

The problem is =>

```
 _______________________________
|         Parent LWC            |
|   ___________                 |
|  |    LWC    |                | 
|  | canvas A  |                |
|  |___________|                |
|                               |
|   ___________                 |
|  |    LWC    |                |
|  | canvas B  |                |
|  |___________|                |
|                               |
|   ___________                 |
|  |    LWC    |                |
|  | canvas C  |                |
|  |___________|                | 
|                               |
|_______________________________|
```

Having the 3 instances of the canvas LWC A,B,C. I can only use the last one to draw on it, its like if the component A and B wouldnt give me the possibility to focus them. And when I try to draw on them, nothing happens. But the last one (C) works as expected and allows focus on itself.

The canvas LWC Code goes like this:

.HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title={label}>
        <div class="c-container"> 
            <div style="width: 400px"> 
                <lightning-input label="Enter text " type="text" value={name} onchange={signIt}></lightning-input>
                <p>
                    {headerText}
                </p>         
                <p class="slds-m-bottom_small"> 
                    <canvas name="canvasItem" height="200" width="400px" style="border:2px solid rgb(136, 135, 135);
                    background: #ffffff;"></canvas>
                </p>
                <p class="slds-m-bottom_small"> 
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Clear Signature" title="Clear Signature" 
                    onclick={handleClearClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                </p>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

.JS

```
import { LightningElement,api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { fireEvent } from 'c/pubSub';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

let isMousePressed, 
    isDotFlag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0;            
       
let penColor = "#000000"; 
let lineWidth = 1;     

let canvasElement, ctx; 
let dataURL,convertedDataURI; //holds image data

export default class SignatureCanvas extends LightningElement {    
    @api recordId;
    fileName;
    @api fieldName;
    @api label
    @api headerText='To process with current application process, please sign';
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    addEvents() {
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove.bind(this));
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleMouseDown.bind(this));
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp.bind(this));
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mouseout', this.handleMouseOut.bind(this));
        canvasElement.addEventListener("touchstart", this.handleTouchStart.bind(this));
        canvasElement.addEventListener("touchmove", this.handleTouchMove.bind(this));
        canvasElement.addEventListener("touchend", this.handleTouchEnd.bind(this));
    }

     handleMouseMove(event){
        if (isMousePressed) {
            this.setupCoordinate(event);
            this.redraw();
        }     
    }    
    handleMouseDown(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setupCoordinate(event);           
        isMousePressed = true;
        isDotFlag = true;
        if (isDotFlag) {
            this.drawDot();
            isDotFlag = false;
        }     
    }    
    handleMouseUp(event){
        isMousePressed = false;      
    }
    handleMouseOut(event){
        isMousePressed = false;      
    }
    handleTouchStart(event) {
        if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
            this.setupCoordinate(event);     
        }
    };

    handleTouchMove(event) {
        // Prevent scrolling.
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setupCoordinate(event);
        this.redraw();
    };
    handleTouchEnd(event) {
        var wasCanvasTouched = event.target === canvasElement;
        if (wasCanvasTouched) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setupCoordinate(event);
            this.redraw();
        }
    };
    renderedCallback() {
        canvasElement = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
        ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        this.addEvents();
     }
    signIt(e)
    {
        var signText = e.detail.value;
        this.fileName=signText;
        ctx.font = "30px GreatVibes-Regular";
        this.handleClearClick(e);
        ctx.fillText(signText, 30, canvasElement.height/2);
    }
    downloadSignature(e)
    {
        dataURL = canvasElement.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        this.downloadSign(e);
    }

    @api propertiesSetup(message) {
        this.requestedSignature(message);
    }

    requestedSignature(destinyRecordId)
    {
        console.log('destinyRecordId');
        console.log(destinyRecordId);
        dataURL = canvasElement.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        //convert that as base64 encoding
        convertedDataURI = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'signatureDataResponse', {payload: [
            {fieldAPIName: this.fieldName, propertyName: 'fileData', value: {
                fileName: 'signature.jpg',
                base64: dataURL,
                recordId: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(destinyRecordId)).recId,
            }}]});
    }

    downloadSign(e)
    {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = '.jpg';
        link.href = dataURL;
        link.click();
    }
    handleClearClick()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    }

    setupCoordinate(eventParam){
        const clientRect = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = eventParam.clientX -  clientRect.left;
        currY = eventParam.clientY - clientRect.top;
    }

    redraw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = penColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;        
        ctx.closePath(); 
        ctx.stroke(); 
    }
    drawDot(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = penColor;
        ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, lineWidth, lineWidth); 
        ctx.closePath();
    }

}
```

I've been stucked in this problem for 2 days, I would be more than glad if you can give me any advise on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Two questions, shouldn't you be querying the element in `connectedCallback()`, also can you query via attribute (i.e. `name`, `id`, etc.) instead of just the HTML element

Comment: @BryanAnderson Not connected callback, that's too soon. You have to wait for renderedCallback at earliest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let canvasElement, ctx;
```

Is defined outside the class, and therefore exists in the static module scope. That means that only one copy of that symbol exists across *all* instances of that module. You can use this technique to store, for example, a global counter of how many instances of your component exist, or shared data.

To have your component store its own copy, the symbols must be inside your class. First, move them inside the class:

```
// ...
export default class SignatureCanvas extends LightningElement {    
    canvasElement;
    ctx;
    // rest of class
```

Then reference them with `this.`:

```
renderedCallback() {
    this.canvasElement = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
    this.ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
```

I go in to a lot more detail about scopes in LWC over in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/359780/2984).

Comment: thank you so much, so I did and its working now. I also replace the querySelector 'canvas' for a data-id unique key. As suggested in comments section.

But your answer was the one which did the trick